# Ошибка апача: gd warning: one parameter to a memory allocation multiplication is negative or zero

Tags: apache, gd, warning

В логах постоянно выскакивает:

> gd warning: one parameter to a memory allocation multiplication is
> negative or zero, failing operation
> gracefully

Что это вообще значит ?

Answer (score 1):

Что кто-то неверно тянет underlying C-код. Если апач не имеет никакого отношения к обработке графики, то надо искать использование gd в PHP-коде, однако, скорее всего, там получится разве что навесить заплатку, а проблема решится через обновление пакета php5-gd или php-gd.